# FBSDKAppInvite call back is not get in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am beginner in IOS and want to invite friend via facebook for used my application. I used new framework of the facebook(4.0) and i found that for invite i need to used FBSDKAppInvite.

I setup the deep link in **"Quick Start for App Links Hosting API"**.

I used following code for application invite

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Share via facebbok
- (IBAction)btnShare:(id)sender
{

    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
      content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/863075563772717"];
    //optionally set previewImageURL


    // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                                 delegate:self];   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NSLog(@"result::%@",results);
}
-(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error::%@",error);
}
```

And handle callback in following method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    // Check if the handler knows what to do with this url
    BFURL *parsedUrl = [BFURL URLWithInboundURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    if ([parsedUrl appLinkData]) {
        // this is an applink url, handle it here
        NSURL *targetUrl = [parsedUrl targetURL];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Received link:"
                                    message:[targetUrl absoluteString]
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But i get nil in **[parsedUrl appLinkData]**

I am not understand what i do wrong. I also put URLScheme in Plist.

Any help can be appreciable

**UPDATE**

if i used following method then i get success in delegate method but invite is not send to recipient.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    // Check if the handler knows what to do with this url
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: I would check in your Facebook Application Settings if you have App Center enabled for iOS, I would also check you have a valid itunes store id in your Settings, and finally that your friend doesn't have the app installed already, otherwise invites won't be sent as specified here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#testing